# RSS Feed Android app that expires?

Tags: android, rss, feed

I've seen many RSS feed android app examples. But the type of feed that I'm trying to return does not need to go into a list view. It provides an active code for a website that ends up expiring usually an hour, sometimes two hours later.

Here is an example of the feed.

> code – 11/29/2012Thursday, November 29, 2012 5:23 PMCode: AlmostDecember Valid: Website Location: Home Expires: 3:30 PM PDT [1826103687] Worth: 6 Points

On the website, that number in the bracket shows up as a countdown and says expired when the time has come. Normally there is only at most 1 code. But occasionally there are 2 or maybe 3. I need the app to display only the active codes, not the ones that have expired. And i would still like to have that countdown timer there. Does anyone understand what i mean? Ive looked at most of the rss feed posts here, and none of them have been able to help me. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please simplify your question.

Comment: So in simpler terms, i need the rss feed to show up in my app. But i need it to only appear if it has not expired. It expires at a specific time, and somehow the number in the bracket of the feed needs to show up as a countdown timer, and when its done, it expires and no longer shows up on the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this coundDownTimer to expire the feed data in your view

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: thats not quite what i meant. I need the countdown timer to go off of what the feed is telling me. I dont know when the countdown timer is going to expire. Its different everytime.

Comment: it is not the full code and was meant to give you just the hint.To implement this you need to first calculate the difference between the expire time and current time and just set the count down timer for that calculated time.

Comment: oh ok, now i just have to figure out how to turn that number in the bracket into that difference.